# Why is my embeded Image not always displayed?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i did a simple rewrite of [this bot](https://top.gg/bot/577100622847934464) in python.
It fetches a link and uses an API to return an Imageurl.

Here's the relevant Code:

```
@bot.command(name='ss')
async def screenshot(context, *args):
    if len(args) != 1:
        await context.channel.send("Error Missing Inspection Link!")
        return
    await context.message.add_reaction("✅")
    #Getting the Imageurl in a Class (sgg) in another Python File
    sgg.getscreenshot(args[0])
    while sgg.imglnk == "":
        sleep(0.2)
    e = discord.Embed(description=sgg.imglnk)
    e.set_image(url=sgg.imglnk)
    print(ppretty(e._image))
    await context.channel.send(embed=e)
```

This does work sometimes, other times it doesn't. (See Image below)

[image]

I checked the Library and found out that the Imageurl is placed in the class member `Embed._image`.
So to see if i'm maybe getting a malformed URL or something i [ppretty](https://github.com/symonsoft/ppretty) printed the class member.
It returned the correct URL for both tests.

```
https://s.swap.gg/rca4ofNZx.jpg
{'url': 'https://s.swap.gg/rca4ofNZx.jpg'}
https://s.swap.gg/DG-7kjyu6.jpg
{'url': 'https://s.swap.gg/DG-7kjyu6.jpg'}
```

So on to my question, does anyone have a clue why it sometimes correctly displays the Image and other times just doesn't?

Comment: Those are some pretty massive images, I wonder if you are getting rate limited.

Comment: @derw by discord? I mean I don't get rate limited by the external API, otherwise I wouldn't get the Image URLs.